# Building Android app for PlayBook custom layout folder?

Tags: android, android-layout, blackberry-playbook

I am currently repacking my Android application for the Blackberry playbook but I am having some issues with the layout.
I have a custom layout for the Nexus 7 which I would like to use on the Playbook. This layout is contained in layout-sw600dp. I know this folder naming convention only came into place in Android 3.0+ and as the Playbook uses Android 2.3.3 this is not used.

The playbook currently seems to be using resources in the layout-xlarge folder. Layouts in this folder are geared towards 10 inch tablets and look poor on the Playbook.

Is there anyway I can test if the device is a Playbook and make it load the same layouts as the nexus 7 without changing the xlarge layouts.

Answer (score 2):

I am using layout-xlarge-v9 (by version of gingerbread, which should(1) not be in any xlarge tablet)

Edit to add a note about qualifier precedence and version qualifier

You need to use the version qualifier at the end.

```
layout-xlarge-v9
layout-xlarge-land-v9
```

Also, this gets version 9 and higher, so your old layout-xlarge should be now:

```
layout-xlarge-v11
layout-xlarge-land-v11
```

I agree on being annoying that it considers itself xlarge

(1) should, because honeycomb was designed for that, but you may find some low-end Android tablets that do, but probably you don't care that much about that segment